# Is >58 hours to create an index normal? Should I cancel and try again?

Tags: mysql, innodb, index

I have an InnoDB table with ~43,964,557 rows containing 20.5 GiB of data (not counting existing indexes).

```
mysql> show table status like 'backpack_items';
+----------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name           | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows     | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+----------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| backpack_items | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 43964557 |            501 | 22063579136 |               0 |   7406682112 |  10485760 |           NULL | 2014-10-27 14:12:09 | NULL        | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+----------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (11.80 sec)
```

I'd like to create an index of 3 INT columns, so I ran the query.

```
mysql> CREATE INDEX `defindex-quality-level` ON `backpack_items` (`defindex`, `quality`, `level`);
```

It's still chugging, 58 hours later.

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-------+------+-----------+---------------+---------+--------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id    | User | Host      | db            | Command | Time   | State             | Info                                                                                       |
+-------+------+-----------+---------------+---------+--------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1077 | root | localhost | traderep_site | Query   | 209716 | copy to tmp table | CREATE INDEX `defindex-quality-level` ON `backpack_items` (`defindex`, `quality`, `level`) |
| 54172 | root | localhost | NULL          | Query   |      0 | NULL              | show processlist                                                                           |
+-------+------+-----------+---------------+---------+--------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is this normal? Is there something I could have done to make it faster?

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem - 20GB is not that big! Could you post a SHOW CREATE TABLE backpack_items?

Comment: @Vérace Too long for a comment, so https://privatepaste.com/2f735cc48e

Comment: How much memory do you have on that machine?

Comment: @Mihai 16 GB, although I think my MySQL cache setting is a bit low.

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway - when I try to access URL (privatepaste). What are your my.cnf settings?

Comment: [Pastebin mirror](http://pastebin.com/sx4mt4UX), [my.cnf](http://pastebin.com/tzybbqAX)

Comment: I checked the logfile (which would have been good to do earlier, I suppose) and I'm getting a bunch of `150118  3:42:16 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted`, which definitely seems to indicate a problem. Thing is, what would the issue be? There's plenty of disk space left and my understanding is that it'll sort on-disk if there's not enough memory. I went ahead and killed it and started over in case it was just a fluke. If it wasn't, it wasn't going anywhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of sort_buffer_size?  200M might be reasonable on your machine.  (A sort *might* be involved in the index creation.)

Keep in mind that it will rebuild all the indexes.  Still 58 hours is unreasonable.

What is the value of innodb_buffer_pool_size?  It may be using that.  It should be about 11G for that size machine, assuming you are using only InnoDB.